# calculating age of a person in logical way in python without using built in functions

Tags: python, logic

```
date=raw_input("Enter Date:")

month=raw_input("Enter Month:")

day=raw_input("Enter day:")

date1=raw_input("Enter Date:")

month1=raw_input("Enter Month:")

day1=raw_input("Enter day:")

int(date,month)

int(date1,month1)

int(day,day1)

d=date1-date

m=month1-month

da=day1-day

print d,m,da
```

trying this program but getting an error
an integer is required

Comment: What exactly is it that you expect e.g. `int(date, month)` to do? Please read the documentation on [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) and [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int). And what does `date` mean anyway - do you mean `year`?

Comment: hey man i got the answer to the question from 
user3343234 is it ok now @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 2):

The `int()` function doesn't work like that:

- Firstly, it takes one argument ([the second is optional and is the base](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int), which is irrelevant in your case).
- Secondly, you need to assign the result to a variable.

Thus

```
int(date,month)
```

should be

```
date = int(date)
month = int(month)
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you wanted it like this.

```
date=raw_input("Enter Date:")

month=raw_input("Enter Month:")

day=raw_input("Enter day:")

date1=raw_input("Enter Date:")

month1=raw_input("Enter Month:")

day1=raw_input("Enter day:")

date = int(date)
month = int(month)

date1 = int(date1)
month1 = int(month1)

day = int(day)
day1 = int(day1)


d=date1-date

m=month1-month

da=day1-day

print d,m,da
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Subject "calculating age of a person in logical way in python without using built in functions" and the Solution approach is however not ok if inbuilt module are not used.

Approach:
You should get the current date first and then the date of birth of the person, and finally find the difference between them, Which you can get via multiple ways.

1) use the datetime or module and time inbuilt module (Recommended approach).

```
import datetime
now = datetime.date.today()
currentyr = now.year
```

else

2)  use string way- the Way you approached is also going to return the sought output.

However the error is due to the fact int()- converts integer number represented as string to integer value, and raw_input() will return you a string.

Comment: yeah what i preferred was calculating it through which year i give not the current year function